# Convert Date String to Long in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, type-conversion, long-integer

There are some basic conversions questions already.

As I'm new to MongoDB, need help for this specific conversion:

Last modification date is being saved as String(**"last_modification" : "/Date(1520430205000)/"**) data type in my document.
I have to get only `numeric(1520430205000)` value from the field and convert it to long as well.

After conversion, the last modification value should be `1520430205000` as **long** data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$trim](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/trim/#exp._S_trim) to remove all the characters that are not representing digits and then run [$toLong](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toLong/) operator. Both operators are available in MongoDB 4.0 or newer. Try:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            last_modification: {
                $trim: {
                    input: "$last_modification",
                    chars: "/Date()"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            last_modification: {
                $toLong: "$last_modification"
            }
        }
    },
    { $out: "collection" }
])
```

[MongoDB Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7in2mMP3Fbo)

EDIT: You can use [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/index.html) to modify existing collection

Comment: Thanks mickl, it worked. but it did not update the value in the collection. Could you please help for updating the value in the collection as well?

Comment: @DevkinandanChauhan modified my answer